# Proving that the following statement is false.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation, problem-solving

I proved that A is TRUE since f is continuous on a bounded interval and thus a minimum must exist.
But for B I can't figure out how to prove that it is true or false. How would you prove B?

[image]

Comment: What if $f(x) =0$ but $E\cap F =\emptyset$ ?

Comment: Is $F $ a subset of the plane or the real line? The definition above looks like it is a closed ball centred on $(1,2)$ of radius 5.